# Why does it compile?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
            var cv = (new CustomValidator()
            {
                 ErrorMessage="Formato de telefone inválido",
                 ControlToValidate = "txtTelefoneIni", //<-- see the extra comma
            });
```

Comment: it's legal, cv becomes a new CustomValidator. CV's fields are explicitly initialized instead of passing params via constructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it is legal syntax.

Really, it is.

When you're constructing an object using the object initializer syntax, you're allowed to leave a trailing comma after the last item, even if you end the initializer block there and then.

The reason behind it is probably that it makes it easier to come back and edit it later, as forgetting to add a comma after the previously-last-item is the #1 compile-time-problem with object-initializers.

Comment: I've heard that it was left legal for the benefit of people who write code generators.  Who knows?  Looks kinda sloppy to me.

Comment: It's also nice from a version control standpoint - you can add another entry without modifying any lines, so the diff is cleaner.

Comment: I'm two minds on this to be honest. Personally I don't add those commas, I add them when I need them, but I also see the point about code generators, which I also use, so it's not a perfect solution either way. Anyway, it's here to stay.

Comment: Personally I also like that someone down-voted this. It's like "Hey, I disagree with the C# spec!!!!1111oneoneeleven", and then not commenting on what the problem was with my answer.

Comment: A trailing comma is legal with enumerations too.  I think it makes editing easier.  If you want to change the order of your items, you don't have to fix the commas afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It's intentional. Also works on enum members. (so it's easier to add more stuff)

Answer (score 2):

Why should it not compile?

This type of syntax is legal in Python as well.

Comment: I thought it because SQL ANSI and JScript doesnt allow us to do such thing.

Comment: IE not allowing trailing commas in JavaScript has been the source of many small bugs for us. Although it's not so much that IE doesn't allow it, it just adds an `undefined` element to the end of an array.

Comment: SQL and JScript are other languages, and they are not C# 3.0 or Python.

Answer (score 2):

It compiles because it is valid C# syntax.  You can also do the same thing with arrays

string[] meh = { "a", "b", "c", };

Answer (score 2):

It is part of the [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047(VS.80).aspx#cs3spec_topic5): Object initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's allowed.
Generally, allowing trailing comma in such forms (and actually using that "privilege") is useful so that programmers can add more items to the list without the risk of having forgotten to add comma at the end of the previous item.

Answer (score 1):

Its a valid syntax in C#

lets see

```
var c = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 ,};
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it was already valid in C.

My favorite reason to use such a syntax (especially when defining enums) is that when you add an item to the list, the source control sees changes in one line only (the new one). It doesn't tag the previusly one as modified (because of added comma). Much more readable diff.

My 2-cents.